# Services Unable to Connect to SQL Server with TLS 1.2 Enabled and TLS 1.0 Disabled

Tags: ssl

As a pre-discussion point, my development team at work is no help, so asking me to ask them will not work.

We have software that has multiple servers that connect back to a SQL Server. All servers are running Server 2016 and the db is SQL Server 2017. Our customers want to exclusively run TLS 1.2. Well, in testing our latest software build, my service team and I cannot get our services to run without also running TLS 1.0. The service just won't start and we get an error:  [image]

I've blocked out the app name for privacy reasons since it's custom software. That error is from the client-side. I don't get any corresponding errors on the SQL box or in any SQL logs. When I run a Wireshark trace and it doesn't have TLS 1.0 enabled, it just goes back and forth with TDS handshakes and never connects. Something I notice is when I go into SQL Server Configuration Manager is that on the SQL Server Network Connection area, it doesn't have any certificates associated with it.

Comment: Maybe this: https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/it-operations-management/unified-infrastructure-management/20-1/installing/pre-installation-planning/install-and-configure-your-database-software/microsoft-sql-server/support-for-tls-v1-2-microsoft-sql-server.html .  Pay attention to the **Note** .

Comment: Does your application support TLS1.2?

Comment: @vidarlo, yeah I've asked the dev team that a million times and they claim yes, but I'm trying to prove if that is true or not. I'm getting the error I posted when I turn on our service without TLS 1.0 enabled. If I enable TLS 1.0 it works no issues. Our system works as designed, but customers want TLS 1.0 off. Sorry long answer, but I'm having to go at this alone a bit to help guide our dev team to what may be the issue since they aren't fluent in security things.

Comment: If you're using something ancient like ADO.NET you should specify that. You also need to specify the .NET Framework version(s), and what if any .NET configuration changes to support TLS 1.2. Client and Server.

Comment: Hi @GregAskew. Yeah we use good ol'ancient ADO.NET. I was doing some more digging on my own last night and I found a registry key that told .NET 4.6 to use TLS 1.2. It was setup at my customer's site and not on my dev team's test lab. Once we mirrored the setup, their system broke as well so hopefully I've gotten them to where they can fix. I was just trying to figure that portion out. Regretfully I don't code here so I'll leave the .NET fix to them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found what I needed and broke our test system so this is now in the capable hands of my dev team.